# timer, handler, runnable, im lost

Tags: timer, text-to-speech

The plan.....

User clicks start button--->tts says something (this works fine)----->Timer starts (this now crashes project)

The timer method.....

Timer starts onTick----->When timer finishes tts says something------>Loop so timer starts again------>Process continues until cancelled.

My dilemma, the timer crashes the project. so a)The timer is written incorrectly, b) the method call is written incorrectly, or c) I need to go take 2 aspirin and watch a movie.  Any help would be appreciated  :)

I'll post code in the comments.  In having a problem posting here.

Comment: I am having problems posting the code.  I will try when I get home from work.

Comment: for the onClick....


       Button Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                tts.speak(voice[2], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                tts.speak(voice[0], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(voice[4], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(voice[5], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

                        Timer1.start();
            }
        });

Comment: That starts the timer. ....